# Zip File - Download - Then Unzip

Tags: javascript, php, unzip, zip

I'm getting really confused here. So here's whats going on in my project. The user clicks download then select directory to save the file, the file will be a zip file. After that I want to extract that zip file in the same directory the users chooses. Is this even possible in one script?

Here is my php code

```
<?php 
require_once('connect.php');
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath($_GET['uniq']);

// Name of the zip derive from the database
$zipname = $_GET['name'] . '.zip';
// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }   
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
?>
```

If its not possible another question. Is it possible to let user choose a zip file then after that it will be extracted at some client directory ie. `C://xamp/extracthere/` using javascript.

Comment: You can't force the client to unzip a payload.  Once they've downloaded the payload it's up to them what they do to it.  Think about it, you don't even know for certain if the client has an unzipper installed, let alone what it is (a commandline tool, WinZip, etc), and just think of the carnage that could potentially ensure if I included a malicious payload in the zip file.

Comment: @GordonM I'm actually creating a software in which the user won't have access to the drive. I need to do this all in the software. I get what your trying to say. So I've come across another solution in which the user will have to choose a zip file that he/she wants to extract. So far its successful for me. Thank you

Comment: Adding a gatekeeper layer between private files and a user is perfectly fine and is quite common practice, but there's still no way you can force the client to unzip a payload.  Browsers are deliberately designed that way.

Comment: @GordonM tried it and it works just fine using the unzipper module. catch is  the user have to save the zip file in the specified directory

Comment: In that case the behaviour is still dependant on the client.  They have to have this unzipper module installed and they have to download it to the correct place.  You can't guarantee either.

Comment: @GordonM I'm well aware of that. the fact is that we are selling our product with all its functionality already installed so no problem with that.

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that in the question then! Along with details of the "unzipper module" you're using.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once the user has downloaded the file to their machine, it's beyond your control. You can't force them to unzip it, or do anything else with it for that matter.

Imagine if you could control the files on a user's local disk, it would be a hacker's dream. This is impossible using both PHP and JavaScript, for similar reasons in each case.